# Ajax query works when adding new post but doesn't work when update an entity

Tags: ajax, symfony

I have two Select box one for the Countries and the second for the cities and the second one depends from the selected choice of the first one.

I the code is as the example **Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms** in the documentation **http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data**

All things work fine when adding a new post , but when trying do update a post, the **Ajax query** to display cities doesn't work .

This is the controller

```
// newAction
/**
* @ParamConverter("agence", options={"mapping": {"agence_slug":"slug"}})
*/
public function newAction(Agence $agence, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $travel = new Travel();
    $form = $this->createForm(new TravelType($agence), $travel);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        //....
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Dashboard/Travel:new.html.twig',
    array(
        'form'   => $form->createView() ,
        'agence' => $agence,
        ));
}

//editAction
/**
* @ParamConverter("agence", options={"mapping": {"agence_slug":"slug"}})
* @ParamConverter("travel", options={"mapping": {"travel_id":"id"}})
*/
public function editAction(Travel $travel, Agence $agence, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $form = $this->createForm(new TravelEditType($agence), $travel);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
        //....
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Dashboard/Travel:edit.html.twig',
    array(
        'form' => $form->createView() ,
        'travel' => $travel,
        'agence' => $agence,
        ));
}
```

**travelType** and ti works good

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;

//........
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\Country;

class TravelType extends AbstractType
{
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
  //....
  $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Country $country = null) {
        $cities = null === $country ? array() : $country->getCities();

        $form->add('destination', 'entity', array(
            'class'       => 'AppBundle:CityWorld',
            'choices'     => $cities,
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'property'    => 'name',
            'label' => 'Destination',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-10', 'placeholder' => 'Destination'),
        ));
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
            $data = $event->getData();

            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getCountry());
        }
    );

    $builder->get('country')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
            // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
            $country = $event->getForm()->getData();

            // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
            // the parent to the callback functions!
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $country);
        }
    );

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function ($event) {
        $event->stopPropagation();
    }, 90000000000000); // Always set a higher priority than ValidationListener

}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Travel'
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return null;
}
}
```

This is **TravelEditType**

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
//........
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\Country;

class TravelEditType extends TravelType
{
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options) ;

 }

 public function getName()
 {
    return null;
 }
}
```

This is the form and javascript code

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form" {{ form_enctype(form) }} >
//.............
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $county = $('#country');

$county.change(function () {
    // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');

    var data = {};
    data[$county.attr('name')] = $county.val();
    // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: data,
        success: function (html) {
            // Replace current position field ...
            $('#city').replaceWith(
                    // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                    $(html).find('#city')
            );
            // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it without parameter in URI:

```
dashboard_city_ajax:
    path:  /citiies/ajax
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:TravelDashboard:ajaxCities }
```

And send data with POST:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '{{ path('dashboard_city_ajax') }}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { agence_slug: '{{ agenceSlug }}' },
```

You can receive it in controller:

```
$request->request->get('bar', 'default value if bar does not exist');
```

Comment: Sorry , I Have removed the Json response , it works without it. I have update my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your route matching. There is many way to solve problem. Try just include in your ajax route `requirements` for matching route or in $.ajax function use another route, for example

The simplest way for you (if you don't want rebuild your controller) is just rebuild your route and put in the first place your ajax route like :

```
dashboard_city_ajax:
    path:  /{ajax}/{agence_slug}/citiies
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:TravelDashboard:ajaxCities }
    requirements:
         ajax: ajax

$.ajax({
        url: '{{ path('dashboard_city_ajax', {'agence_slug': agence.slug, 'ajax': 'ajax' }) }}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
```

But the right way IMHO is get your data from request. For example

```
vplanning_ajax:
    path:   /ajax
    defaults: { _controller: VplanningPageBundle:Page:Ajax }


function getData(init) {
    $.post(
        {{ path('vplanning_ajax') }},
        {
          agence_slug: agence.slug,
          yourdata2: 'yourdata2
         } ,
        function ( data ) {
            handleData(data);
        }
    );
}
```

And in your Controller your just do

```
$agence_slug = $this->request->request->get('agence_slug');
$yourdata2 = $this->request->request->get('yourdata2);
```

...

Comment: Sorry , I Have removed the Json response , it works without it. I have update my question